# How can I edit the .env file from filament dasboard?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-filament, .env

I'm building a new laravel dashboard using the Filament library. I want to add some settings that allow the user to change some `.env` values namely the website URL and the DEBUG mode. This is my implementation:

```
Card::make()->schema([
    TextInput::make('siteUrl')
        ->label('URL')
        ->placeholder('http://localhost')
        ->helperText('Required for file uploads and other internal configs')
        ->required(),
    Toggle::make('debugEnabled')
        ->label('Is Enabled')
        ->helperText('Enable/Disable debug mode to help debug errors')
]),
```

This successfully saves the settings to the database but I can't figure out how I can persist the changes into the `.env` file.

Saving the settings is handled by filament internally, so I can not execute the code that will edit the `.env` file. Something like a hook or a callback would help in this situation. I hope the issue is clear.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Generally it is not a good idea - for this, you need to make .env writable by webserver. More good idea - move some config variables to database and read them with service provider on boot stage.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Usually, the .env files have a pretty simple structure, so if you **really** want to edit them, something as simple as `file_put_content` could help

Comment: Thanks for the insight and thanks for the quick response Maksim. I'm new to laravel so I'm still trying to figure out how things work. I'll give this a try

Comment: Hi there Nico. Editing the .env file is not the issue. But saving the settings is handled by filament internally so there is no way for me to execute the code like some hook or callback

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. If writing to the file is not the problem, why is that mentioned as a problem in your post?

Comment: BTW: config:cache stop working when you done this feature - this impact production performance. Than you need another entitiy - eg LocalConfiguration.